# What is Headless PWA. What is difference between PWA and Headless PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, headless, headless-cms

Basically i have understanding on Headless CMS/Headless commerce Architectures.

- A headless CMS, is a back-end only content management system built from the ground up as a content repository.
- That is content management systems(Example: Sitecore, etc) will expose the content as a services (CAAS). React or Angular weba application will be accessing the contents as a service to display it in UI. In this way CMS systems are decoupled from the Front end and know as Headless CMS. React or Angular will not site on CMS instead it will deployed separably. The term “headless” comes from the concept of chopping the “head”.
- Commerce will always be headless, because it will be decoupled from the front end application. i.e front end applications will consume the dynamic data via webservices from commerce engines.

Now What is Headless PWA?

Headless CMS + Headless commerce + PWA features = Headless PWA ?

Answer (score 0):

PWAs are web apps that run on the client (user's device). They by definition can not be headless.